# Sonar Qube issue with Random Number Generator in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have used the below code to generate a random number between 0 and 1000

```
Random number = new Random();
number.Next(0, 1000);
```

But in sonarqube its an issue and is suggesting to go with this

```
var randomGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
```

How we can pass min and max value to RandomNumberGenerator.

Comment: "its an issue", what is the issue? Does it give any explanation as to why you should go with the second approach?

Comment: Weak Cryptogragy, System.Random class relies on pseudorandom number generator it should not used for security-critical application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Create()`, you can use the `GetInt32()` method to generate a random number for specific boundaries using `RandomNumberGenerator`. Please see the below example.

```
var randomGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(0, 1000);
Console.WriteLine(randomGenerator);
```